# Given a recurrence relation for the coefficients of an analytic function $f$ find a functional equation for which $f$ is a solution

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $f(z)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n$ be an analytic function on some open set $U\subset\mathbb{C}$ and assume that the coefficients of the above series are all positive and satisfy
$$\frac{1}{a_n}=\frac{b}{a_{n-1}}+\frac{c}{a_{n-2}},\quad n\geq 2,$$
where $b$ and $c$ are some constants. Is it then possible to find some functional (differential) equation for which $f$ is a solution?

Comment: $b_n:=\frac{1}{a_n}$ satisfies a Fibonacci-type recursion. Therefore you get a closed formula for $a_n$. With that you can test on a functional equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $u_n = 1/a_n$, we have
$$ u_n = b u_{n-1} + c u_{n-2}$$
Let's suppose the quadratic $r^2 = b r + c$ has two distinct roots $r_{+}$ and $r_{-}$.  Then the solutions
of this recurrence are
$$ u_n = A_+  r_+^n + A_- r_-^n$$
for arbitrary constants $A_+$, $A_-$.  Thus
$$ a_n = 1/(A_+ r_+^n + A_- r_-^n) $$
This has ordinary generating function

$$ f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^n}{A_+ r_+^n + A_- r_-^n} $$
which does satisfy a functional equation
$$A_+ f(r_+z) + A_- f(r_- z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n = \frac{1}{1-z} $$

Note that the coefficients $A_+$ and $A_-$ of this 
functional equation can be obtained from $a_0$, $a_1$, $r_-$ and $r_+$:

$$ \eqalign{A_+ &= \frac{a_0 - r_- a_1}{a_0 a_1 (r_+-r_-)}\cr
A_- &= \frac{a_0 - r_+ a_1}{a_0 a_1 (r_- - r_+)}}$$

Comment: Thank you! Is it possible to find such an equation in case the reccurence is given by $\frac{1}{a_n}=\frac{b+cn}{a_{n-1}}+\frac{d}{a_{n-2}}, n\geq 2$? It seem that in this case obtaining an explicit formual for $a_n$ is a bit more complicated.

Comment: More than a bit, I think.